# Scanning in Ubuntu 20.10 with HP OfficeJet Pro 8025 scanner

Tags: hp, scanner, 20.10, hplip

I can’t seem to get the HP OfficeJet Pro 8025 to scanning Linux regularly. The scanning seems to work only sporadically, even though the unit is detected in Ubuntu.

I tried installing the HPLIP software, but the install does not succeed in Ubuntu 20.10, something related to Python dependencies not being met. The HPLIP software uses `simple-scan` for scanning documents.

The `simple-scan` software sometimes works, but a lot of the time the scanning seems to be sporadic. I am using a USB connection and the `lsusb` command seems to detect the printer/scanner combo fine.

Printing with CUPS almost works every time; I only had an issue where the printer wouldn't print once.

Comment: Hey summerdays2020! Please paste the output of `dpkg -l hplip` in your question by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 1):

The command `scanimage -L` seems to show the scanner name and info. If I copy the scanner name (HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series all-in-one) and running the following command,

`simple-scan HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8020_series all-in-one` simple-scan will detect the scanner.  I found this article useful.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=329760